# AcroFields' funcion setField doesn't add apostrophe on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, acrofields

When adding a string that contains an apostrophe by using the AcroFields' method "SetField", the function removes the apostrophe from the string.

I tried to use a single accent but it was removed as well.

Comment: Replace your apostrophe with this character **`**

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this issue is because the font that is being used doesn't support certain characters, there are two solutions:

1. Replace the apostrophe character with `
2. Set the field to use a font that does support the apostrophe like this:

   ```
   BaseFont fieldFont = 
   BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\timesnr.ttf", 
                                BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 
                                BaseFont.EMBEDDED); 

   myDoc.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty("myField", "textfont", fieldFont, null);
   ```